# Spring Boot & Elastic Search - failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot, connection

I am trying to connect to elastic search via spring boot and port 9300. I can connect to a local elastic search installation. But the remote one brings following error:

> failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}

I tried connecting via telnet which works. Does anyone have a hint for me?

Log:

```
2017-10-17 13:49:05.392  INFO 19733 --- [           main] o.s.d.e.c.TransportClientFactoryBean     : adding transport node : myurl...:9300
2017-10-17 13:49:05.487  INFO 19733 --- [           main] org.elasticsearch.client.transport       : [Armory] failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{myurl...}{192.168.xx.xx:9300}, disconnecting...

org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [][192.168.xx.xx:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness] disconnected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logfile later showed me, what sysout never did :( I had a quite current article on how to install ElasticSearch on Ubuntu 16 (which is quite up to date). But the used elastic version ways NOT up to date :( By far not. So I have to double check my dependencies and update to latest elasticsearch server version...